# spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges for Linode Cloud provider

Tags: kubernetes, linode

I am trying to lock down my kubernetes cluster and currently use cloudflare on the front in I am trying to whitelist cloudflare's IPs

this is in my service yaml:

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 130.211.204.1/32
  - 173.245.48.0/20
  - 103.21.244.0/22
  - 103.22.200.0/22
  - 103.31.4.0/22
  - 141.101.64.0/18
  - 108.162.192.0/18
  - 190.93.240.0/20
  - 188.114.96.0/20
  - 197.234.240.0/22
  - 198.41.128.0/17
  - 162.158.0.0/15
  - 104.16.0.0/12
  - 172.64.0.0/13
  - 131.0.72.0/22
```

after applying this manifest, i can still access the loadbalancer URL from any browser! is this feature not working or perhaps I configured this incorrectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service:

> When using a Service with spec.type: LoadBalancer, you can specify the
>   IP ranges that are allowed to access the load balancer by using
>   spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges. This field takes a list of IP CIDR
>   ranges, which Kubernetes will use to configure firewall exceptions.
>   This feature is currently supported on Google Compute Engine, Google
>   Kubernetes Engine, AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service, Azure Kubernetes
>   Service, and IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service. This field will be ignored
>   if the cloud provider does not support the feature.

May be your cloud simply does not support it.

You can use other things that allow blocking by source IP, like nginx or ingress-nginx. In ingress-nginx you just specify list of allowed IPs in annotation `ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range`.

If you want to go Nginx or other proxy route - don't forget to change Load Balancer Service `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local`. Otherwise you will not see real client IPs.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that... but you mentioned i still keep the Service(s) as a "Load Balancer" Type?  what do i expose to to cloudflare? it sounds like a client would still hit the created load balancer(s) but use the ingress controller on each node to determine if the sourceIp is on the list to block?

Comment: Clients would hit the loadbalancer and then be proxied to Nginx or whatever proxy you choose.

Comment: *update* my hosting provider www.linode.com doesn't offer this support yet. thanks for help tho!